# How can I get VMware Workstation Player to STRETCH the desktop of the host to match the guests window frame?

Tags: vmware

How can I scale the Guest Host without changeing the Guest Host Resolution in VMware, similar to how "Scale Mode" works in Virtual Box? So scaling the frame of the hosts window that contains the the VM scales the entire vm, but does not change the actual resolution.

**1. My Host is Windows 10.**

**2. I am using the FREE vmwave Workstation Player 16**

**: More Detail :** Basically VirtualBox has this feature, a stretch guest feature, but they have removed all 3D Acceleration support in 6.1+ VMware still has the acceleration and is the only real option I know of Qemu for windows dose not use acceleration at all. So as far as I know there is no choice but to use vmware or an old version of virtualbox. As VMware supports acceleration I would rather just use it... but without getting a scale function to work it is not really viable as I simply can not read anything on my vm desktops!

[image: VMWare at 800x600]

This is a 800x600 winXP vmware running on my 4K Screen.

[image]

This is the same desktop in vmware after I have dragged the window larger. See how the actual resolution of the guest OS has been increased?

[image]

Here you can see a 800x600 XP Desktop running in VirtualBox. Note how after dragging the edges of the screen and making the window larger, the desktop is still 800x600.. it is simply stretched?

**: Additional Question :** I tried using the windows10 Magnifying Glass to enlarge the screen so I could see it better but it was super cumbersome and hard to use. Is there a magnifying glass app where you can just choose a window and make it larger or just drag a magnifier out and eveything under it will be larger with no "scrolling" effect" when you reach the sides?

Comment: Try the View and then Guest fit options. I am using VMware Workstation Pro and that is how it works. I set my VMware window in the host that I want and then size my guests inside that as I choose. See if this helps.

Comment: I do not seem to have any options like this?

Comment: What is "guest host"?  There is a guest OS (which runs in the VM), and there is the host OS (the OS that VMware Workstation/Player is running on). "Guest host" is contradictory.

Comment: If you want to stretch the *guest*, VMware (Workstation) Player does not provide UI to configure that.  VMware Workstation (Pro) does (at least for full screen mode).  You could try manually modifying `%APPDATA%\VMware\preferences.ini` and setting `pref.autoFitFullScreen = "stretchGuestToHost"`, but I don't remember offhand if Player will honor that.  Also note that that setting affects only full screen (and not windowed) mode anyway.

Answer (score 2):

A bit of an old thread, but I just wanted to thank **jamesdlin**.
The solution works with VMware Workstation 16 Player (aka the free version); besides the `pref.autoFitFullScreen = "stretchGuestToHost"` also add `pref.autoFitGuestToWindow = "FALSE"`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).